# How to configure to inject JPA EntityManagerFactory insted of EntityManager into spring beans

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-orm

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(datasource());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
    em.setJpaProperties(properties());
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("JPA_PU");
    em.setPackagesToScan("com.test.entity");
    return em;
}
```

From my bean declaration in my persistence config which injects this 
 bean into this

```
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "JPA_PU")
 private EntityManager em;
```

but not

```
 @Autowired
 private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit about why you want to do this?  It does not seem like a very good idea and it would be a rather unusual thing to do.

Comment: @scottb I'm working on some batching in my application where I intend to use multi threading to improve performance , so I want to problematically mange transactions, since  Entity manager is cannot be shared so I want to get a entityMangerFactory  to get entityManger object per thread

Comment: The life cycle of injected resources is ordinarily managed by the container.  If you have multiple beans that require an entityManager instance, one expects that the container will be managing a pool of such instances so that your beans will each have an instance, yes?

Comment: yes, I'm using pooling but  here, I just need a way to inject entityManagerFactory